# OnClick and enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm creating a to-do list and would like to provide users with two ways of adding items to the list. The first, is by pressing the ENTER key while inputting data in the "inItemText" input field. The second, is by clicking the "btnAdd" button.

I have been able to get the button to work. However, I'm unable to get the ENTER key to work.

Also, I'd like to add functionality to the edit button... Any advice would help!

```
<body>

  <h1>To Do List</h1>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="inItemText">
    <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
  </div>

  <ul id="todoList"></ul>

</body>
```

JS

```
function addListItem(){
    var text = $("#inItemText").val();
    $("#todoList").append("<li><input type='checkbox' class='done' />" + text + "<button class='delete'>Delete</button><button class='edit'>Edit</button></li>");
    $("#inItemText").val("");
    $("#inItemText").focus();
}
function deleteItem(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

function finishItem(){
    if($(this).parent().css('textDecoration') === 'line-through'){
        $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'none');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
    }
}

$(function(){
    inItemText.focus();
    $("#btnAdd").on('click', addListItem);

    $(document).on('click','.delete',deleteItem)
    $(document).on('click','.done',finishItem)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way

```
$('#inItemText').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    addListItem();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `addListItem` whenever the `keyup` event of the enter key happens

```
$('#inItemText').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    addListItem();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! that worked great! Any ideas o how to get the edit button to work?

Comment: You should probably ask that in a new question, but I'd at least try something of your own first. Questions that don't show effort on the asker's part are frowned upon.